# Dynamically load dropdown values depending on row in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables, jeditable

I have a mvc web app with the with the jquery code from datatables and jeditable. In one of my views i have a table with projects, users and departments. every project have a responsible person. Now i would like to give the admin the possibility to change the respnsible person with a dropdown created on server side. To secure he don´t break any department structures he should only be able to choose member from the department where the project is located. To solve this i have to load the  dropdown depending on the entry in the department column. 
as far as i understand the datatables, the dropdown would become loaded if the page is created so it shouldn´t be possible for me to change it depending on the department row. Have anyone a hind for me how i could solve my problem?

Here is the html code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#ProjectTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("ProjectTableHandler", "ManageDepartment")",
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sDom": 'ftrlp',
            "bInfo": false,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sSearch": "Search in your departments for projects: ",
                "oPaginate":
               {
                   "sNext": 'next',
                   "sLast": '&gt;&gt;',
                   "sFirst": '&lt;&lt;',
                   "sPrevious": 'prev'
               }
            },
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "sName": "ID", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false, "bVisible": false },
                { "sName": "Id" },
                { "sName": "Name" },
                { "sName": "RespUser" },
                { "sName": "Department" }
            ]
        });
        oTable.columnFilter({ sPlaceHolder: "head:after", "aoColumns": [null, null, null, null] });
        oTable.makeEditable({
            "aoColumns": [null,
                { onblur: 'submit' },
                null,
                null],
            sUpdateURL: "@Url.Action("UpdateProject", "ManageDepartment")",
        });
           });

</script>
<hgroup>
    <h1>Manage the projects of the own departments</h1>
</hgroup>

<fieldset>
    <legend id="ManageProjectsHeadline">Projects </legend>
       <table id="ProjectTable" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.Label("ID")</th>
                <th>@Html.Label("Id")</th>
                <th>@Html.Label("Name") </th>
                <th>@Html.Label("RespUser", "Responsible user") </th>
                <th>@Html.Label("Department", "Department")</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <input type="button" class="AskButton" id="Ask" value="?" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

and the table handler:

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(BusinessObjectNotRetrievableByIdException), View = "BusinessObjectNotFound")]
[HandleError]
public ActionResult ProjectTableHandler(JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{
    List<Project> AllProjects = ProjectManagement.GetProjectsOfDepartmentList(UserManagement.GetAllOrganisationUnitsFromHoDOrDA(UserManagement.GetSingle(Session.Current.UserComparison.GetUserId()))).ToList().ConvertAll(i => (Project)i);
             var isIDSearchable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_1"]);
    var isNameSearchable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_2"]);
    var isPISearchable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_3"]);
    var isDepartmentSearchable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_4"]);
    IEnumerable<Project> filteredProjects;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch)) filteredProjects = AllProjects.Where(a => isNameSearchable && a.Name.ToUpper().Contains(param.sSearch.ToUpper()) || isPISearchable && a.SecureEntity.User != null && (a.SecureEntity.User.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(param.sSearch.ToUpper()) || isDepartmentSearchable && a.SecureEntity.OrganisationUnit != null && a.SecureEntity.OrganisationUnit.Name.ToUpper().Contains(param.sSearch.ToUpper()));
    else filteredProjects = AllProjects;
    filteredProjects = filteredProjects.Where(a => (isVisibilitySearchable && vis == "" || ((a.SecureEntity.Visibility >= 0 && a.SecureEntity.Visibility <= 3) && a.SecureEntity.Visibility == Convert.ToByte(vis)))).Distinct();
    var isIDSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_1"]);
    var isNameSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_2"]);
    var isPISortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_3"]);
    var isDepartmentSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_4"]);
    var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);
    Func<Project, string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex == 1 && isIDSortable ? Convert.ToString(c.Id) : sortColumnIndex == 2 && isNameSortable ? c.Name : sortColumnIndex == 4 && isPISortable ? c.SecureEntity.User.LastName : sortColumnIndex == 3  && isDepartmentSortable ? c.SecureEntity.OrganisationUnit.Name : "");
    var sortDirection = Request["sSortDir_0"];
    if (sortDirection == "asc") filteredProjects = filteredProjects.OrderBy(orderingFunction);
    else filteredProjects = filteredProjects.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction);
    if (param.iDisplayLength != -1) filteredProjects = filteredProjects.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
    var ProjectStringList = new List<string[]>();
    foreach (var Project in filteredProjects)
    {
        var url = Url.Action("ProjectDetails", "Projects", new { id = Project.Id });
         ProjectStringList.Add(new string[] { Convert.ToString(Project.Id), "<a href='" + url + "'>" + Convert.ToString(Project.Id) + "<a>", Project.Name, "" + Project.SecureEntity.User.FirstName + " " + Project.SecureEntity.User.LastName,  Project.SecureEntity.OrganisationUnit.Name });
    }
    return Json(new { sEcho = param.sEcho, iTotalRecords = AllProjects.Count(), iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredProjects.Count(), aaData = ProjectStringList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you tried. tough to understand the essay

Comment: i shorted my code and pasted it in